# Returning boolean with Neo4j when request succeeds/fails

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to make a query that would return me a boolean when the query succeeds or fails. So it would be true when it succeeds and false when it fails:

This is my request and after the `RETURN` is what I have tried so far `neo4j`:

```
MATCH (n:User),(d:Song) 
WHERE n.username = "syord" 
  AND d.title = "Hello" 
CREATE (n)-[r:PURCHASED]->(d) 
SET n.totalStars = 999999  
RETURN CASE 
WHEN n IS NULL 
  THEN false 
  ELSE true 
END 
AS n
```

This returns true when it succeeds but when it fails I get nothing : `(no changes, no records)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Underlying idea

```
MATCH (n:YourLabel) RETURN count(n)>0 AS result;
```

### Result

```
╒════════╕
│"result"│
╞════════╡
│false   │
└────────┘
```

### Applied to your concrete query

```
MATCH (n:User),(d:Song) 
WHERE n.username = "syord" 
  AND d.title = "Hello" 
CREATE (n)-[r:PURCHASED]->(d) 
SET n.totalStars = 999999  
RETURN count(n)>0
AS n
```

Comment: That works exactly as I wanted it to, but why does the `count(n)>0` return true/false?

Comment: After the amount for `n` has been determined, the resulting boolean expression `1>0` is evaluated by Cypher, which leads to the value `true` or `false` that is returned by `RETURN`.